# How to deploy 2 services in an Apache Ignite cluster

Tags: ignite

I have a spring boot service that configures ignite at startup and executes Ignition.start(). There are 2 more services also on spring boot that need to be placed in one Ignite cluster. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are running Apache Ignite in embedded mode using maven dependency. For sharing the same Ignite instance across services, you need to create an Ignite cluster in distributed mode and then connect to the same Cluster from all the services using Thin/Thick client as per your need.

For e.g Creating Ignite cluster using Docker refer to the link: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/installing-using-docker
There are other options available to create Ignite cluster.

Once the Cluster is created then you can use a Thick/Thin client to connect to the same cluster.

Please refer :
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/getting-started/concepts